# Install mSATA SSD on Lenovo A720

Tags: installation, ssd, msata, lenovo-desktop-computer

I just purchased a Lenovo A720 and they have a more expensive version than what I purchased that has a SSD.  I figured to buy the SSD separately and save myself a little money and install it myself.

I've taken off the base cover but there doesn't seem to be a place to put the SSD.  Here are some pictures - **any suggestions**?

[image: Left side as seen from the rear of the computer]
[image: Right side as seen from the rear of the computer]
[image: the middle of the motherboard]

There are places on the web where people have said they've done the installation but not how or with pictures.

Edit: [On Lenovo forums, someone had done it](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaCentre-Desktops-Home-Servers/Installing-mSATA-drive-in-IdeaCentre-A720/m-p/901561/highlight/false#M4504) but doesn't say how - I've replied asking how.

Added two more pictures per request:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please update your post to say you mean **mSata SSD**, not just **SSD** - otherwise you will get a significant number of repetitions of my original comment!  Pictures from a higher view would be helpful too.

Comment: mSATA drives connect to the miniPCIe connector

Comment: Appears to be the bottom image of all of them.  The small black header that says "SSD" on the mobo should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I obviously bought the wrong size SSD. I didn't know there were [smaller (mSATA) versions](https://superuser.com/a/427880/134769).

The mSATA goes right next to the HDD and below the DVD drive to the left of the right speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Lenovo manual to compare with this, the msata SSD area on MB is correct.  Just do a google search for Lenovo a720 manuals.